# Function.InvokeAfter trouble

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I'm trying to delay each call to StockData with 5 seconds in order to get by an API call restriction. Can't seem to get it done right, what am I doing wrong?

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Stocks"]}[Content],
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Function.InvokeAfter(Table.AddColumn(Source, "StockData", each StockData([Full Name])), #duration(0,0,0,5)),
    #"Expanded StockData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "StockData", {"Name", "Value.1. open", "Value.2. high", "Value.3. low", "Value.4. close", "Value.5. volume"}, {"StockData.Name", "StockData.Value.1. open", "StockData.Value.2. high", "StockData.Value.3. low", "StockData.Value.4. close", "StockData.Value.5. volume"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded StockData",{"Size", "Short Name", "ISIN"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Related code if anyone would like to try it out:

```
let StockData = (stock as text) =>

        let
            Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=" & stock & "&outputsize=compact&apikey=RG5AM4ORXWE1X0V8")),
            #"Time Series (Daily)" = Source[#"Time Series (Daily)"],
            #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(#"Time Series (Daily)"),
            #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Value", {"1. open", "2. high", "3. low", "4. close", "5. volume"}, {"Value.1. open", "Value.2. high", "Value.3. low", "Value.4. close", "Value.5. volume"})
        in
            #"Expanded Value"
in StockData
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What are they? What is happening?

Comment: Yes sorry about that @QHarr,
Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Table to type Function.
Details:
    Value=Table
    Type=Type

Comment: What step does that occur on? Step 2?

Comment: @QHarr Yes that is correct. 
I do not however need to have the Function.InvokeAfter in that place as long as there is a delay.
I have also tried to add this and remove the Function.InvokeAfter in step 2, then the code runs but to fast: 

Delay = 2,

DelayTimer = Function.InvokeAfter(() => 2+2, #duration(0,0,5,Delay)),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `Function.InvokeAfter` to the function (not to the table), and you need to change the syntax slightly to pass arguments to that function.

Rewrite the second line as:

```
#"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "StockData", each Function.InvokeAfter(()=>StockData([Full Name])), #duration(0,0,0,5))),
```